# What is getHtml() in Magento

Tags: magento

In product filter phtml file Magento call a function getHtml().

What is getHtml() in Magento and what was diff between getHtml() & getChildHtml().

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Programmatically `getHtml()` is a public method for calling the protected rendering method `Mage_Core_Block_Template::_toHtml()`, while `getChildHtml()` attempts to find a block instance from the calling block's `_children` array and return the value of its rendering using the more common `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::toHtml()` method.

Architecturally I'm not 100% clear on any intent beyond shaving off minuscule processing overhead, inline translation, and cache writing for these filter block instances.